# Build Query from multiple selected items from listbox in c#.net

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to transfer multiple selected items from one list box to another list box and then send a query to display the database from selected items of list box 2.that means display the table using where clause and the where conditions are those selected items from list box 2.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    {
        ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
        TextBox1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    if (!arraylist1.Contains(ListBox1.Items[i]))
                    {
                        arraylist1.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!ListBox2.Items.Contains(((ListItem)arraylist1[i])))
                {
                    ListBox2.Items.Add(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));

                }
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));
            }
            ListBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ListBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if(ListBox2.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                if(!arraylist2.Contains(ListBox2.Items[i]))
                {
                    arraylist2.Add(ListBox2.Items[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < arraylist2.Count; i++)
        {
            if(!ListBox2.Items.Contains(((ListItem)arraylist2[i])))
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(((ListItem)arraylist2[i]));
            }
            ListBox2.Items.Remove(((ListItem)arraylist2[i]));
        }
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

I have written this to transfer from one list box to another.But how do i write a query for displaying the data using where clause and the condition for where clause is taken from list box 2.Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query you can add code to retrieve data using where clause at end of your `Button2_Click` function,

Add Sql connection using Ado.net or what ever framework you are using for db connection execute query which I have added to your db and get result from it.

Now from these result you can bind new list box (I think you know how to bind from retrieved result from query as you already bind the list box)

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ListBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if(ListBox2.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                if(!arraylist2.Contains(ListBox2.Items[i]))
                {
                    arraylist2.Add(ListBox2.Items[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < arraylist2.Count; i++)
        {
            if(!ListBox2.Items.Contains(((ListItem)arraylist2[i])))
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(((ListItem)arraylist2[i]));
            }
            ListBox2.Items.Remove(((ListItem)arraylist2[i]));
        }
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

    // Construct the query with where clause
    string whareClause = string.Join("','", arraylist2.Select(e=>e.Value));
    string query = "select * from ListBox2 where items in ('"+ whareClause + "')";

    // Call your db using Ade.net
    // Bind your result to new list box

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```